# How to properly use WHERE in an UPDATE in Node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

In the following code, my PUT works correctly, currently the PUT updates all the rows in the table but I would like it to change only the matched rows.

How can I fix this issue?

```
 app.put('/api/alluserpls', (req, res, ) => {
     // récupération des données envoyées
     const formData = req.body;

     connection.query('UPDATE alluserpls SET ? WHERE id = id', formData, err => {
         if (err) {
             // Si une erreur est survenue, alors on informe l'utilisateur de l'erreur
             console.log(err);
             res.status(500).send("Erreur lors de la modification des users");
         } else {
             // Si tout s'est bien passé, on envoie un statut "ok".
             res.sendStatus(200);
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: What is in `formData` ?

Comment: @Adder formDate , was nothing is error on code clean ^^

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a WHERE clause after SET?

That would be something like :

```
'UPDATE alluserpls SET //your update// WHERE //your condition//'
```

Comment: Hi , yes 
I know that, only I don't know what I should put as a condition

Comment: @Adder Souvik Das , i have try UPDATE alluserpls SET ? WHERE id = id' but evrything change

Comment: The id has to come from somewhere. `id=id` is always true, so you update all records. You should create a `PUT` endpoint which is for changing just one record and which has an id in the path which you then can use.

Comment: @Adder , can you more explain ? or do you have example ? or Doc for more information ? pls

Comment: I'm not an expert at this. This should help you: https://alligator.io/nodejs/express-routing/ Look for `app.put`